# Performing list of Google Search using Python code

Tags: python, google-chrome, search

I'm pretty new to programming, and I didn't start to learn python yet. In general I have a long  list of codes which I need to search in google for example:
`123`, `124`, `125`, `126`
I find code which can do that in python [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/):

which look like this:

```
try: 
    from googlesearch import search 
except ImportError:  
    print("No module named 'google' found") 


query = "Geeksforgeeks"

for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2): 
    print(j)
```

but I don't know how to make it search more than one item from my list in a time. I tried to create a list in python but it didn't work. Can you guys help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend just setting up a collection of strings you want to search for.
Then iterate through the collection, search for that string, and store the results.

```
from googlesearch import search 

list_of_queries = ["Geeksforgeeks", "stackoverflow", "GitHub"]
results = []

for query in list_of_queries:
    results.append(search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2))

print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Taylor for quick answer. It work very well, but i have one more problem, it generate output as <generator object search at 0x03FBDDF0>, I'm trying to see it as output as URL with list() function, but it don't work. Are you able to help mi also with this?

Comment: Ok i actually manage to do it i just needed to add:                                                     
for result in results:
    print(list(result))